# Why will my lambda skill cdk construct not accept the cdk.secretvalue parameters i am passing in?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, alexa-skills-kit

Using aws-cdk": "2.47.0"
I am getting the following error when deploying my stack

Resolution error: Synthing a secret value to . Using a SecretValue here risks exposing your secret. Only pass SecretValues to constructs that accept a SecretValue property, or call AWS Secrets Manager directly in your runtime code. Call 'secretValue.unsafeUnwrap()' if you understand and accept the risks..

```
Object creation stack:
  at new Intrinsic (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/intrinsic.js:1:680)
  at new SecretValue (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/secret-value.js:1:592)
  at Function.cfnDynamicReference (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/secret-value.js:1:2713)
  at Function.secretsManager (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/secret-value.js:1:2202)
  at HltbStack.retrieveSecrets (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/lib/hltb-stack.ts:55:45)
  at new HltbStack (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/lib/hltb-stack.ts:27:12)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/bin/hltb.ts:20:1)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
  at Module.m._compile (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
  at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
  at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
  at phase4 (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:649:14)
  at bootstrap (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:95:10)
  at main (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:55:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/john/Desktop/Production/alexa skills/hltb/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:800:3)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
  at /Users/john/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpx/index.js:268:14
```

This is what my stack looks like

```
import { Stack } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import { Skill } from "cdk-alexa-skill";
import * as path from "path";
import { Props } from "../bin/hltb";
import * as ssm from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ssm";

export type SkillConfig = {
  alexaVendorIdSecretValue: string;
  lwaClientIdSecretValue: string;
  lwaClientSecretSecretValue: string;
  lwaRefreshTokenSecretValue: string;
};

export class HltbStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: Props) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const skillBackendLambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, "Function", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      handler: "handler.handler",
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, "/../src/handlers")),
    });

    const { alexaVendorId, lwaClientId, lwaClientSecret, lwaRefreshToken } =
      this.retrieveSecrets(props);

    const skill = new Skill(this, "hltbSkill", {
      endpointLambdaFunction: skillBackendLambdaFunction,
      skillPackagePath: "src/skill-package",
      alexaVendorId,
      lwaClientId,
      lwaClientSecret,
      lwaRefreshToken,
    });
  }

  private retrieveSecrets(props: Props): {
    alexaVendorId: string;
    lwaClientId: string;
    lwaClientSecret: cdk.SecretValue;
    lwaRefreshToken: cdk.SecretValue;
  } {
    const alexaVendorId = ssm.StringParameter.valueForStringParameter(
      this,
      props.alexaVendorIdSecretValue
    );

    const lwaClientId = ssm.StringParameter.valueForStringParameter(
      this,
      props.lwaClientIdSecretValue
    );

    const lwaClientSecret = cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager(
      props.lwaClientSecretSecretValue
    );
    const lwaRefreshToken = cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager(
      props.lwaRefreshTokenSecretValue
    );

    return {
      alexaVendorId,
      lwaClientId,
      lwaClientSecret,
      lwaRefreshToken,
    };
  }
}
```

here is the type for the skill

```
export interface SkillProps {
    readonly endpointLambdaFunction?: lambda.IFunction;
    readonly skillPackagePath: string;
    readonly alexaVendorId: string;
    readonly lwaClientId: string;
    readonly lwaClientSecret: cdk.SecretValue;
    readonly lwaRefreshToken: cdk.SecretValue;
}
```

I am passing it a cdk.SecretValue for the lwaClientSecret and client lwaRefreshToken so why am i getting the error message?

Comment: What is your CDK framework (not CLI) version? Please include the full error, including the traceback.

Comment: @gshpychka im using aws-cdk": "2.47.0" and that is the full error received after a cdk deploy

Comment: There should also be a traceback - include that as well. Basically, the entire console output. This is to make sure that the error is caused by the lines you are suspecting and not something unrelated.

Comment: @gshpychka added the trace

Comment: Are you setting the `"@aws-cdk/core:checkSecretUsage": true` feature flag in `cdk.json`?

Comment: @fedonev Yes i am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty: `"@aws-cdk/core:checkSecretUsage": false`

---

The CDK tries to protect you against leaking secrets into the CDK artefacts. The error message is generated by one of these checks. In your case, though, it seems the error message is a false positive. From what I can see, your code does not expose plaintext secrets<sup>*</sup>.

You can force the CDK to shut up by disabling the [@aws-cdk/core:checkSecretUsage](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/%40aws-cdk/cx-api/FEATURE_FLAGS.md#aws-cdkcorechecksecretusage) feature flag (default `false`, recommended `true`):

> Enable this flag to make it impossible to accidentally use SecretValues in unsafe locations (config)

Ideally you'd address the root cause (perhaps the 3rd Party `Skill` construct?) so the check can remain enabled.  But disabling the flag should silence the error.

---

* Your `retrieveSecrets` method does not actually "retrieve" the secrets. The CDK is not querying SecretsManager for the actual secrets.  That would be unsafe.  Rather, the `cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager` method generates a CloudFormation [dynamic reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) to the secret. In the template, you'll get something like `{{resolve:secretsmanager:lwaClientSecretSecretValue:SecretString:::}}`. Perfectly safe. The actual secret value is only resolved cloud-side by CloudFormation when you deploy the app.  You can review the template artefact in `cdk.out` and verify this for yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much @fedonev That has solved my issue (I'm too ashamed to say how long this has had me stumped :)). There is definitely some dodgy behaviour in that construct which i might investigate further and possibly raise to AWS but your answer has helped unblock me so thank you.

Comment: @JohnNezzi Glad to help!  BTW, I didn't mean to imply the 3rd party construct is somehow dodgy.  That conclusion isn't justified, in my opinion.